# SQL Count all Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to calculate a count on a query, however I got some problem.

The original query works well.
It gives me 1 row with the right count (3200):

```
select count(e.entity_id) 
from `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `review` AS `rt` 
ON rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `rdt` 
ON rdt.review_id = rt.review_id
INNER JOIN `review_store` AS `store` 
ON rt.review_id=store.review_id AND store.store_id=0
```

I needed to alter this query in order to get other values so now, this is the new count query:

```
select count(e.entity_id) 
from `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `review` AS `rt` 
ON rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `rdt` 
ON rdt.review_id = rt.review_id
LEFT JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt` 
ON vt.review_id = rt.review_id
INNER JOIN `review_store` AS `store` 
ON rt.review_id=store.review_id AND store.store_id=0 
GROUP BY `rt`.`review_id`
```

Second query gives me back not 1 row with the correct count (3200) but 3200 rows with each one with a different count.

What I would need it would be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM
( `second_query`)
```

Or any other solution that gives me back the right count

Comment: What is the problem with the first query? you said `I needed to alter this query in order to get other values so now` what other values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select TOP 1 count(e.entity_id) OVER() [Total Count]
from `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `review` AS `rt` 
ON rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `rdt` 
ON rdt.review_id = rt.review_id
LEFT JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt` 
ON vt.review_id = rt.review_id
INNER JOIN `review_store` AS `store` 
ON rt.review_id=store.review_id AND store.store_id=0 
GROUP BY `rt`.`review_id`
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(select `rt`.`review_id`
from `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `review` AS `rt` 
ON rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `rdt` 
ON rdt.review_id = rt.review_id
LEFT JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt` 
ON vt.review_id = rt.review_id
INNER JOIN `review_store` AS `store` 
ON rt.review_id=store.review_id AND store.store_id=0 
GROUP BY `rt`.`review_id`) AS T1
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() [total COUNT], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `rt`.`review_id` ORDER BY e.en' at line 3

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 count(e.entity_id) OVER() [Total Count] from `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` I' at line 1

Comment: second query works fine ... strage because I tried a similar query I got error, however thank you

Comment: may be you are trying with e.entity_id instead of `rt`.`review_id` in inner query. can you please vote me.

Answer (score 1):

Take away the group by clause.

Comment: this gives me a single row but a bigger count result (review_detail contains almost 3 result for row .. ) so i get 9000 as count

Comment: That's actually expected.  Depending on what you want, you might need more than one query.

Comment: basically I would just need to count all rows

Answer (score 0):

When you have the query without a `group by`, it will implicitly make a group of the whole result, and you get the count for that single group.

By adding the `group by` you are creating one group for each review, and the result is a count for each group.

Just remove the `group by` clause from the query, and you get back the count for the entire result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select TOP 1 count(e.entity_id) OVER (partition by '1')
from `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `review` AS `rt` 
ON rt.entity_pk_value = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `rdt` 
ON rdt.review_id = rt.review_id
LEFT JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt` 
ON vt.review_id = rt.review_id
INNER JOIN `review_store` AS `store` 
ON rt.review_id=store.review_id AND store.store_id=0 
GROUP BY `rt`.`review_id`
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 count(e.entity_id) OVER() [partition by '1'] from `catalog_product_entity` AS ' at line 1